# JavaFX8: Blurry font rendering within ScrollPane (Caspian Theme)

Tags: java, css, java-8, javafx-8

I have a font rendering issue on Labels at JavaFX 8 (Windows JDK 8u102 x64) within ScrollPanes. Label's font should be LCD type smoothed, but it's actually rendered with the default "gray" smoothing type.

I use a CSS entry to set the application wide smoothing type. I already checked if the CSS entry is applied (I changed the font and font color); only the "-fx-font-smoothing-type" is ignored.

```
.root {
     -fx-font: 12px "Verdana";
     -fx-font-smoothing-type: lcd;
}
```

When I put the label outside of the scrollpane the font rendering is okay.

Anyone have an idea for a workaround?

I port a Java 7 application to Java 8. With JRE 7u80 it works.

Comment: Did you enable anti-aliasing on the scene?

Comment: No, antialiasing is not enabled.

Comment: I'm using the "Caspian" Theme, with the "Modena" Theme it works.

Comment: Do you have any specific test case or github project that can be used to verify this issue? As you mentioned it worked on 7u80, it does look like regression and issue in java.